# How to change shortcut for switching between work-space in fedora 20?

Tags: fedora, gnome, gnome-3, fedora20

I am using a text editor which uses shortcut
`ctrl+alt+arrowup/arrowdown`
which is default key for switching workspaces in fedora 20. So i need to change the shortcut key to make it work in text editor. I changed the shortcut from 
Settings>Keyboard>Shortcutsbut still ctrl+alt+arrowup/down switches workspace. So how do i remove the shortcut key to make it work in my text editor? 
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open `dconf-editor`, in the left pane navigate to `org > gnome > desktop > wm > keybindings`. Then in the right pane scroll down until you see the two keys:
`switch-to-workspace-down` and `switch-to-workspace-up`:

[image]

Click on each key value to edit the shortcuts (so you end up with e.g. `['<Super>Page_Down']` and `['<Super>Page_Up']` respectively).
Restart your session.